# Form inserts data in database but how to mail the new entry to myself?

Tags: php, forms, function, email

This form inserts the order-data of my customers in my database. How can I get every new order as well formated clean text e-mail, using http://php.net/manual/de/function.mail.php ? I have no idea how to handle it.

**PHP code**

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "db_name", "password") or die ("Keine Verbindung zum MySQL-Server möglich"); 
mysql_select_db("db_name", $con) or die ("Keine Verbindung zur Datenbank möglich");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

if (isset($_POST['button']))
{
foreach ($_POST AS $key => $postvar)
    $_POST[$key] = stripslashes($postvar);

$_POST['name'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$_POST['strasse'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['strasse']);
$_POST['plz'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['plz']);
$_POST['ort'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ort']);
$_POST['mail'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mail']);
$_POST['anzahl'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['anzahl']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `bestellungen` (`name`,`strasse`,`plz`,`ort`,`mail`,`anzahl`,`datetime`)
                VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."', '".$_POST['strasse']."', '".$_POST['plz']."', '".$_POST['ort']."', '".$_POST['mail']."', '".$_POST['anzahl']."', '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."');";

$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
if (!$result) echo mysql_error();
mysql_close($con);
Header("Location: success.php");
exit();
?>
```

**HTML code**

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="bestellung.php">

<span class="form_anzahl">Anzahl</span>
<select class="input_anzahl" name="anzahl"/>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select><span class="form_artikel">Artikelname</span>

<span class="form_name">Name</span>
<input type="text" name="name" class="input_name" placeholder="Vor- und Nachname" required="required"/>

<span class="form_strasse">Straße</span>
<input type="text" name="strasse" class="input_strasse" placeholder="Straße und Hausnummer" required="required"/>

<span class="form_plz">PLZ</span>
<input pattern="[0-9]{5}" name="plz" class="input_plz" placeholder="12345" required="required"/>

<span class="form_ort">Ort</span>
<input type="text" name="ort" class="input_ort" placeholder="Ort" required="required"/>

<span class="form_mail">E-Mail</span>
<input type="email" name="mail" class="input_mail" placeholder="E-Mail" required="required"/>

<div id="redtxt_insert_bestellungen">Preis: 13,12 Euro</div><br>
<button type="submit" name="button" value="abschicken">bestellen</button>
<div class="spacer"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: First set the SMTP settings (if you have SMTP server)
Then after MYSQL Insert, call the mail function with SMTP parameters.
I am sorry if I don't unserstand your questin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chnage you `foreach` loop like so:

```
$message='';
foreach ($_POST AS $key => $postvar):
    $_POST[$key] = stripslashes($postvar);
    $message.= "$key : $postvar \n";
    endforeach;
```

then:

```
mail('me@example.com', 'New Order', $message);
```